# some question of Hartshorne book Lemma (II.4.4)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a valuation ring of a field $K$. Let $T={\rm Spec}~R$ and let $U={\rm Spec}~K$. In Harthorne book, Lemma (II.4,4) is to prove that given a scheme $X$, to a morphism of $T$ to $X$ is equivalent to giving two points $x_0,x_1$ in $X$, with $x_0 \in \bar{\{x_1\}}$ and an inclusion $k(x_1)\subseteq K$,such that $R$ dominates the local ring $\mathcal{O}$ of $x_0$ on the subscheme $Z= \bar{\{x_1\}}$ of $X$ with its reduced induced structure.
In proof, I don't understand following statement:

$k(x_1)$ is the function field of $Z$. So we have a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_{x_0,Z}$ to $R$ compatible with the inclusion $k(x_1) \subseteq K$.

Comment: I have another question. Why $T$ is reduced? What's meant by this? Reduced induced should refer to an equivalence class of  morphisms. It is $Z$ that is reduced induced by the definition (or more precisely the inclusion $Z\hookrightarrow X$, right? )
When we get $T$ reduced, the map $T\rightarrow X$ factors through $Z$. But for this, according to exercise 3.11 c) , we need $Z$ and $T$ have homeomorphic underlying topological spaces. It seems for me that $Z$ is bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheme $\rm Z$ is defined as the closure of $\{x_1\}$ which means that $x_1$ is the generic point of $\rm Z$. It also follows that $\rm Z$ is irreducible. Then it is a general fact that the function field of an irreducible scheme is the residue field at the generic point.

Now the scheme $\rm T$ has a unique closed point $t_0$ and a unique generic point $t_1$. Then local ring of $\rm T$ at the point $t_0$ is $\rm R$ because $\rm R$ is already local ; the local ring of $\rm T$ at the generic point is the fraction field $\rm K$.

Because you have a morphism of schemes $\rm T \to \rm Z$, you have then a local morphism of local rings $\mathcal O_{\rm Z, x_0} = \mathcal O \to \rm R = \mathcal O_{\rm T, t_0}$ and a morphism $\mathcal O_{\rm Z, x_1} = k(x_1) \to \rm K = \mathcal O_{\rm T, t_1}$. Then first inducing the second.

Comment: To have a function field I believe a scheme must be integral, not just irreducible.  However, since Z is given the reduced induced subscheme structure it is both reduced and irreducible, hence integral.

Comment: Why does the first induce the second? The first may not be injective, a priori.