# How to understand Lemma 4.4 in Hartshorne, Chapter 2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have essentially the same question as in [some question of Hartshorne book Lemma (II.4.4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303859).

However, even with the answer in that question, I am still confused what does ''local homomorphism of $O_{x_0,Z}$ to $R$ is compatible with the inclusion $k(x_1) \subset K$'' mean, and why?

In particular, I noticed there were people asking why this local homomorphism is injective in the comment, therefore I wonder if anyone can explain this more clearly.

Comment: Basically, $Z$ is an integral scheme, so that all the restrictions/localizations morphisms are injective. Actually they can be seen as various inclusions between subsets of $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_1}=K(Z)$. So $k_Z(x_1)=k_X(x_1)$ (that’s important and not always made clear) is actually $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_1}$ and you know it to be injected in $K$. So you can assume everything is already contained in $K$ and you consider inclusions instead of morphisms, so you get injectivity.

Comment: For the compatibility, following up on my previous remarks: you have two morphisms $f_0:\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0} \rightarrow R$ and $f_1:k(x_1)=\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_1}\rightarrow K$. You also have morphisms $z: \mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0} \rightarrow k(x_1)$ and $r: R \rightarrow K$. Compatibility means that $r \circ f_0=f_1 \circ z$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, would you mind elaborating these in the answer?

Comment: I am still confused what is the morphism $z: O_{Z,x_0} \rightarrow k(x_1)$ and why must  $r \circ f_0 = f_1 \circ z$? Would you mind explaining a little bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: If $A\to B$ is a morphism of schemes with $a\mapsto b$, then we have an induced local map on local rings $\mathcal{O}_{B,b}\to\mathcal{O}_{A,a}$. This should be familiar from the definition of a morphism of locally ringed spaces: if you need some jogging of your memory, it may be helpful to recall the affine case and use the universal property of localization.

Step 2: If $A$ is a scheme with $a_1,a_0$ points so that $a_1$ is a generalization of $a_0$, there is a natural map $\mathcal{O}_{A,a_0}\to \mathcal{O}_{A,a_1}$, and it's a localization. You can see this either by calculating on an open affine neighborhood of $a_0$, where it correpsonds to the fact that $R_\mathfrak{q}$ maps to $R_\mathfrak{p}$ by localizing for $\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathfrak{q}$ prime ideals, or from the definition of the stalks as inverse limits over open neighborhoods: any open neighborhood of $a_0$ contains $a_1$ and thus there's a natural map induced on the limits.

Step 3: If $A\to B$ is any map of schemes with $a_0\mapsto b_0$, $a_1\mapsto b_1$, and $b_0\in \overline{\{b_1\}}$, then we also have that $a_0\in\overline{\{a_1\}}$ and the following diagram commutes:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{O}_{B,b_0} @>{}>> \mathcal{O}_{A,a_0}\\
@V{}VV @VV{}V \\
\mathcal{O}_{B,b_1} @>{}>> \mathcal{O}_{A,a_1}
\end{CD}$$

This is a combination of steps 1 and 2. If you want to see it in a more hands-on way, you can let $A$ and $B$ be affine (by selecting an open affine neighborhood of $b_0$ [this contains $b_1$ since open subsets are stable under generalization] and then an open affine neighborhood of $a_0$   [also containing $a_1$ for the same reason] contained in it's preimage) and use the universal property of localization a couple times.

---

Now to apply the above to our situation. In our case, $A=\operatorname{Spec} R$, $a_0$ is the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset R$, $a_1=(0)\subset R$, $B=X$, and $b_0=x_0$, $b_1=x_1$. Rewriting our commutative  diagram, we have

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{O}_{X,x_0} @>{}>> R\\
@V{}VV @VV{}V \\
\mathcal{O}_{X,x_1} @>{}>> K
\end{CD}$$

where the horizontal maps are local maps of local rings. Now we use a couple of universal properties: first, letting $I=\ker \mathcal{O}_{X,x_0}\to R$, the map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_0}\to R$ factors through $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_0}/I$. As $I$ is the kernel of a morphism to a domain, it's prime, and so the map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_1}\to K$ factors through $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_1}/I_I$. We may further note that $I_I$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_1}$ as our map is a local map of local rings where the target is a field. This corresponds to restricting to $Z$ with the reduced induced structure, since $I$ is prime. Replacing $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_0}/I$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_1}/I$ with $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_1}=k(x_1)$ we have the following commutative diagram, where the horizontal arrows are still local ring maps:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0} @>{}>> R\\
@V{}VV @VV{}V \\
k(x_1) @>{}>> K
\end{CD}$$

This commutative diagram is what Hartshorne means by a local homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0} \to R$ compatible with the inclusion $k(x_1)\to K$.

Comment: Hi KReiser, thank you always for the answer. I am wondering does the natural map in your Step 2 have to be injective? I think in our case it is injective because $Z$ is integral, therefore the composite morphism $O_{Z,x_0} \rightarrow k(x_1) \rightarrow K$ is injective, forcing the morphism $O_{Z，x_0} \rightarrow R$ to be injective.

Comment: @Xin This map in step 2 doesn't have to be injective in general (think about the generalization from the origin in $V(xy)$ to the generic point of one of the components). It's injective in our case because $Z$ is integral.

Comment: Also, in your Step 3, the diagram commute, is it because locally it is induced by the same ring homomorphism?

Comment: @Xin If you're talking about inferring the diagram from the affine case, yes.

Comment: @KReiser Btw, does the lemma hold for any local ring $R$ in $K$, not necessarily a valuation ring?

Comment: @wkf that's far enough away that you should ask it as a separate question, in my opinion.